# Vue3 - how to create an instance of component and pass arguments

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a following use case: I have a form and when submitting I want to add another (new) Vue 3 component as an item (**li**) into the unordered list (**ul**). This works for me when doing that this way:

```
data() {
     return {
        some_list: []
     }
},
methods: {
    doSomething(){
    this.some_list.push(
        MyComponent
      );
    }
}
```

**BUT**, I need to pass some **arguments** to that component as well. My component has got some properties defined. I just do not know **HOW** **to pass** those arguments. Just for information: I am using Vue 3 with Javascript, not Typescript.

Comment: You could take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jzbjjk?file=/src/App.vue maybe it will help you

Comment: @Loki thanks for this, I will check definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `v-bind` directive would help with that

```js
data() {
  return {
    some_list: []
  }
},
methods: {
  doSomething(){
    this.some_list.push(
      {component:MyComponent, props:{...theprops}}
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<v-for="{component, props} in some_list">
  <component :is="component" v-bind="props"></component>
</v-for>
```

references

- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components
- https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer!!! It helped and I can confirm it is working for me. Thank you again. Appreciated.